# Efficient way to get configuration elements for a specific plugin in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to find all extensions of `org.example.extension.point` declared in `com.example.plugin`. Is there a more efficient way to do so than doing

```java
List<IConfigurationElement> result = new ArrayList<IConfigurationElement>();
IConfigurationElement[] allConfigElements = 
    Platform.getExtensionRegistry.getConfigurationElementsFor("org.example.extension.point");
for (IConfigurationElement ice : allConfigElements) {
    if (ice.getDeclaringExtension().getNamespaceIdentifier() == "com.example.plugin")
        result.add(ice);
}
return result;
```

?

Comment: An alternative is to look at the IContributor first and then filter on the extension point ID...

Comment: I am afraid I don't see what you mean, could you provide some example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there are no other (more efficient) ways (is this not simple enough?;). In addition I'd use `ice.getContributor().getName()` instead of `ice.getDeclaringExtension().getNamespaceIdentifier()`

I really would like to know why you want to filter by a specific contributor. - I mean if you have to "know" the contributor why are you using the extension point? The main purpose of an extension point is using inversion of control; the main characteristic of using extension points is **not knowing** the contributor. No offense, but probably you are using extension points in a way they are not intended for...

Comment: I need to show a tree which contains bundles and extensions provided by them.

Comment: Then take a look how Eclipses "Plug-in Registry" View is implemented, see class org.eclipse.pde.internal.runtime.registry.RegistryBrowser. This view shows a tree with all plugins and their extensions.